# Sublime text 3: How to wrap selected text in custom string/ tag/ function (laravel language helper example)

Tags: laravel, sublimetext3, laravel-blade

Take a look at this code:

```
<p>This is nice text!</p>
```

What i want to achieve is to select `This is nice text!` and make it like this:

```
<p>{{ __('This is nice text!') }}</p>
```

This is a basic example of laravel language helper. It has more implementations tho.

Comment: Wrapping the selection in arbitrary text can be easily done via snippets. I assume there are several different things you'd like to wrap around the selection; how do you envision selecting which one to use (e.g. key binding, context menu, command palette)?

Comment: @OdatNurd "key binding, context menu, command palette" I think any1 will do really

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking, the easiest way to wrap selected text with other text is to use a [snippet](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) to perform the job. Snippets allow you to insert arbitrary text into the buffer in a few different ways, and also allows for the inclusion of whatever the selected text happens to be at the time the expansion happens.

To see this in action, you can select `Tools > Developer > New Snippet` from the main menu, which will create a snippet template for you. Once that's done, replace the entire content of the file with the following text and save the snippet. Sublime will default to your `User` package as the location, and you can choose any name that you want; just make sure that the extension is `sublime-snippet` so that Sublime will recognize the file. In this example I have named the file `localize.sublime-snippet`.

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
{{ __('${0:${SELECTION}}') }}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>localize</tabTrigger>
    <description>Localize text</description>
    <scope>text.blade</scope>
</snippet>
```

As seen here, snippets are XML files. The link above is to the unofficial documentation on snippets, so briefly we'll just say:

- The content of the `CDATA` section is the snippet text that will expand
- `$` has a special meaning in the snippet body, so if you want to insert a literal `$`, you need to specify `\$` instead
- The `tabTrigger` is a phrase you can use to expand the snippet manually; it's optional
- The `description` is a textual description of what the snippet is for; it's optional
- The `scope` indicates where the snippet applies; it's optional

The snippet content can contain numbered fields like `$0`, `$1` and so on, and when the snippet expands Sublime will position the cursor at `$1` for you to enter text, then jump to `$2` when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and so on until all fields are filled out, which makes the cursor jump to `$0` (the "exit" of the snippet).

Also worth noting that the `scope`  here assumes you are using the [Laravel Blade Highlighter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Laravel%20Blade%20Highlighter) package for your syntax highlighting. If you're not, then while editing a blade file use `Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name` and replace `text.blade` with the first line in the popup instead.

Now with the snippet in place, we can do a few things automatically. First, while in a blade file, you can enter the tab trigger text and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and the content of the snippet will expand, putting the cursor inside of the single quotes (where the `$0` is in the snippet) so you can enter some text:

[image: Sample snippet expansion]

The list of snippets that apply to the current situation is also automatically added to the command palette as commands that are prefixed with `Snippet:`; you can use `Tools > Snippets` from the main menu or just open the command palette and do a command search to see the snippets that apply to the current situation. Here we can see our `localize` snippet being displayed; the description comes from the tag in the snippet, and Sublime also reminds us of how to trigger the snippet.

[image: Snippet in command palette]

So now cycling back to your original question of wrapping text, note that the body of the snippet contains this:

```
{{ __('${0:${SELECTION}}') }}
```

The `${0}` is specifying where the cursor should go when the snippet is done expanding fields (of which there are none), and the `:${SELECTION}` part is saying that the default value of this field should be the selected text.

When you use the `localize`<kbd>Tab</kbd> method of expanding the snippet as above, there is no selected text, so the cursor just ends up sitting in the middle of the string. However, if you trigger the snippet from the command palette, it's possible to select text first. In that case the selected text is replaced by the snippet, but since the snippet captures the selection, you end up with text wrapping your selection:

[image: Expansion via command palette]

For things like this that you do frequently, you can also use the `insert_snippet` command to cause the snippet to expand; in such a case you would select text first to wrap it, but with no selection the snippet would expand with the cursor inside of the single quotes as if you did it manually.

For example, you could create a key binding such as the following:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+l"],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": {
        "name": "Packages/User/localize.sublime-snippet"
    },
    "context": [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.blade" },    
    ]
},
```

The `context` section here makes the binding active only in a blade file and not everywhere similar to how the `scope` in the snippet works; this is because the `insert_snippet` command directly inserts the snippet without doing any checks.

Similarly you could also add this to the right click context menu by creating a file named `Context.sublime-menu` in your `User` package (i.e. the same location as you saved the snippet to above) with the following content:

```
[
    { "caption": "-", "id": "end" },

    {
        "caption": "Localize Blade Text",
        "command": "insert_snippet",
        "args": {
            "name": "Packages/User/localize.sublime-snippet"
        },
    },  
]
```

Here the menu command will always be available regardless of what file you're editing because as mentioned above the `insert_snippet` command doesn't constrain the expansion of the snippet based on `scope`. You could solve that with a small simple plugin, though (not covered here since this answer is pretty massive as it is).

One last thing to mention is that in cases where you're using the `insert_snippet` command directly (that is, when you are not using the command palette or <kbd>Tab</kbd> expansion methods), you can skip some steps here.

The `insert_snippet` command can take a `contents` argument in place of the `name` argument; while the `name` argument specifies the snippet that should be expanded, the `contents` argument just contains the snippet content directly. That saves you the step of having to create the `sublime-snippet` file in the first place.

For your example here, this key binding will do the same as the above one will, but without requiring the snippet file to exist:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+l"],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": {
        "contents": "{{ __('${0:${SELECTION}}') }}"
    },
    "context": [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.blade" },    
    ]
},
```

Comment: amazing, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You could use "Laravel Blade Highlighter" Package for sublime, it gives you auto completion on laravel blade syntax. With your specific query, you can just select the text and hit '{' twice and it will auto wrap the selected text between {{ text }}. This comes in default with sublime text 3.

For all the blade related features check Laravel Blade Highlighter package here : https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Laravel%20Blade%20Highlighter